# UserVote matching query does not exist

Tags: django

I'm having some trouble here and I can't figure out what's going on. I'm working on matching two users if they vote yes to each other, and then storing them in a database based on if they match, and then displaying them. If I manually add the users through admin, that works fine. In fact, if I were to remove the 2nd 'create_vote' method, the first one works just fine and stores the vote in a 'user_vote'object. However, when I add the second create_vote method, which I need to actually create 'matches', it doesn't work and it seems to be having a problem simply creating the vote to begin with.

**tracerback:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/papichulo/Documents/DatingAppCustom/dating_app/views.py", line 144, in nice
    return create_vote(request, profile_id, True)
  File "/Users/papichulo/Documents/DatingAppCustom/dating_app/views.py", line 159, in create_vote
    vote=vote
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 408, in get
    self.model._meta.object_name
dating_app.models.UserVote.DoesNotExist: UserVote matching query does not exist
```

**views.py/methods I use for matching**

```
def create_vote(request, profile_id, vote):
    profile = Profile.objects.get(pk=profile_id)
    UserVote.objects.create(
        user = profile,
        voter = request.user,
        vote = vote
    )
    return redirect('dating_app:mingle')





def nice(request, profile_id):
    return create_vote(request, profile_id, True)


def nope(request, profile_id):
    return create_vote(request, profile_id, False)





def create_vote(request, profile_id, vote):
    profile = Profile.objects.get(pk=profile_id)
    UserVote.objects.get(
        user=profile,
        voter=request.user,
        vote=vote
    )
    if vote:
        if UserVote.objects.filter(
            user = request.user,
            voter=profile,
            vote=True
        ).count():
            npm = Profile.objects.get(request.user)
            npm.matches.add(Profile.objects.get(username=profile.username))

            npm = Profile.objects.get(user=profile)
            npm.matches.add(Profile.objects.get(username=request.user))

            npm.save()
            return render(request, 'dating_app/matches.html', dict(
                match=profile,
            ))
    return redirect('dating_app:mingle')
```

**models.py**

```
class ProfileManager(BaseUserManager):



    def create_user(self, username, email,description,photo, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("You must creat an email")
        if not username:
            raise ValueError("You must create a username!")
        if not description:
            raise ValueError("You must write a description")
        if not photo:
            raise ValueError("You must upload a photo")

        user = self.model(
                email=self.normalize_email(email),
                username = username, 
                description= description,
                photo= photo,

            )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user 


    def create_superuser(self, username, email,description,photo, password):
        user = self.create_user(
                email=self.normalize_email(email),
                password=password,
                username=username,
                description=description,
                photo=photo,

            )

        user.is_admin=True
        user.is_staff=True
        user.is_superuser=True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user




class Profile(AbstractBaseUser):

    class Meta:
        swappable = 'AUTH_USER_MODEL'


    email                       = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email")
    username                    = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    date_joined                 = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joined', auto_now_add=True)
    last_login                  = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last login', auto_now=True)
    is_admin                    = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active                   = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff                    = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser                = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    #what I added
    description                 = models.TextField()
    photo                       = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_photo',blank=False, height_field=None, width_field=None, max_length=100)
    matches                     = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='+', blank=True)



    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['description','photo','email']


    objects = ProfileManager()


    def __str__(self):
        return self.username


    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin


    def has_module_perms(self,app_label):
        return True



class UserVote(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    voter = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='given_vote', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    vote = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('user', 'voter'))
```

Comment: What is `UserVote.objects.get(
        user=profile,
        voter=request.user,
        vote=vote
    )` doing here? You do not use that result anyway, so it will ineed raise an error if it can not find this `UserVote` object.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem  Well, I tried removing it but then nothing happens. No error, but also no vote being created. To be honest, I'm adapting someone else's code to my work. It works on their program, but my program uses a custom user model that I made vs their program simply extended the user model.

Comment: well it will at most do something if `vote` is `True` (because of the `if vote`), and it that case it will check if the vote already exists, and if that is the case, it will add another one. So the logic does not make much sense.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I thought it's comparing the vote of the current user and the user the current user is voting on? I mean it works in this guys program. It's just not working on mine. How would you recommend doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic of the `create_vote` method is a bit off. You probably should remove a (possibly) earlier `UserVote`, and then create the new one. For example with:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def create_vote(request, profile_id, vote):
    profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, pk=profile_id)
    UserVote.objects.filter(
        user=profile,
        voter=request.user
    ).delete()
    UserVote.objects.create(
        user=profile,
        voter=request.user,
        vote=vote
    )
    other = UserVote.objects.filter(
        voter=profile,
        user=request.user,
        vote=True
    )
    if vote and other.exists():
        profile.matches.add(request.user)
        request.user.matches.add(profile)
    return redirect('dating_app:mingle')
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211255/discussion-on-answer-by-willem-van-onsem-uservote-matching-query-does-not-exist).